# In webMethods, Apart from Global Variable feature, Is there any other option to configure desired values?

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

Example:
Assume that there is a string variable called "passcode" .

I have to fetch value for the variable passcode at runtime based on the environments

| Environments | Value |
| --- | --- |
| DEV | abc123 |
| SIT | def321 |
| QA | S1O8F9 |
| PROD | 3a2b1c |

In webMethods, Are there any  alternate solutions to configure and fetch the value at each environment level apart from Global variable option?

Answer (score 0):

Can configure environment variable in db or extended settings --> based on environment options DEV, SIT...

Logic can be written in service for different values or can read configuration from any properties file...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom config file and host that file in the package. The file can be xml, json or even flat file. Implementation is same as any file operations. You can insert the values to cache during package (re)load and create the file if it is missing. You can load the file anyway you want (use external services, db, distributed cache etc).